# . Read in real numbers until 10 positive values have been found. Write out the sum of the 10 positives

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Here's the important part of my code:

```
int realnum, positive = 0, total, poscount;
for (poscount = 1; poscount < 11; poscount++)
{
    cin >> realnum;
    while (realnum > 0)
    {
        total = realnum + positive;
    }
}
cout << "Total of 10 positive values is " << total << endl;
```

I really just don't see what's wrong here. After declaring my integers the program goes into my for, increase the poscount to 2, asks my to input realnum. I put in a positive number (ex: 6), which should in theory add my realnum with positive (which I declared 0) and give total the value (ex: 6 + 0 = 6). It should keep looping until poscount reaches 11 and output the total of 10 positive numbers.

When I run it, I put in 6 and the command prompt just shows 6, nothing happens, and I have to close through the x button. Can someone please tell me what the error is?

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a `while` in the outer loop, to keep the number of so-far positive numbers.
Also, your `total` is uninitialised and you assign `positive` to it, which is just 0?

This is what I have in mind:

```
int realnum, total = 0, poscount = 0;

while (poscount < 10) {
    cin >> realnum;
    if (realnum > 0)
    {
        total += realnum;
        poscount++;
    }
}
cout << "Total of 10 positive values is " << total << endl;
```

Comment: I didn't know += for total += realnum; is total = total + realnum (or at least not yet)!

Comment: Not bad, but how do you intend to survive the user typing in "flunatkoo"? Or 3.14, for that matter.

Comment: In exactly the same way that OP was going to, I am not. In my programming beginnings, we, too, assumed correct input.

Comment: You know now :) There're also -=, *=, /= or bitwise operations &= etc. Happy programming!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `while` with an `if` since currently, once you enter that `while` loop you never exit it.

Also, why are you *always* increasing `poscount`? Shouldn't you only do that if `realnum` is positive? The iteration statement in the `for` loop is allowed to be blank; then you write `poscount++` inside the new `if` block.

You also need to write `total +=` to *increment* the total amount.

These things are easy to spot if you use your debugger.

Comment: I had it something like

 while (realnum > 0)
{
for (poscount = 1; poscount < 11; poscount++)

before but I switched it to the one you're seeing now, to be honest I'm just testing my logic back and forth.

Comment: How is the        while        loop

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I think I've corrected myself (without blatantly copying blurry but also using Bathsheba's tip on replacing my while.

```
int realnum = 1, positive = 0, total, poscount;
if (realnum > 0)
{
    for (poscount = 1; poscount < 11; poscount++)
    {
        cin >> realnum;
        total = realnum + positive;
        positive = total;
    }
}
cout << "Total of 10 positive values is " << total << endl;
```

So far, it seems to work, there's probably a lot of unnecessary things that make it inefficient but I didn't want to copy examples.  *Edit of course I still need to do with the ignoring negative part

**I think I backed myself into the point of no return, ha. I really thought there was an alternate way I was going... Anyways, thanks for your replies, guys. I've always been lurking around here, until I made an account now.**

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to terminate the while loop. And instead of adding positive to realnum, try adding poscount. That should provide the desired result.